# ubuntu 20.04 Desktop: screen terminates after logoff

Tags: gnu-screen

afair

```
$ screen -v
Screen version 4.08.00 (GNU) 05-Feb-20
```

is method to run commands continuously after logout. But on my 20.04 this doesn't work.

```
user@laptop:$ ssh user@machine
   user@machine:$ screen -ls
   No Sockets found in /run/screen/S-user
   user@machine:$ date
   Mi 7. Jun 14:09:19 CEST 2023
   user@machine:$ screen
      user@machine:$ sleep 60
       (ctl-a d)
   user@machine:$ screen -r
   [detached from 501987.pts-0.machine]
   user@machine:$ logoff
user@laptop:$ ssh user@machine "screen -ls; date"
No Sockets found in /run/screen/S-user
Mi 7. Jun 14:09:32 CEST 2023
user@laptop:$
```

"sleep" is just an example, ddrescue or testdisk is what i want to run eg.

SElinux is not installed.

Discovered no hints in /var/log/*.

Any ideas? Or having the same issue?

Kind regards
Maniac_

Comment: Please add the content of `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` and any file in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf.d/` and `/usr/lib/systemd/logind.conf.d/` to your question.

Answer (score 0):

THX for the hint!

```
$ cat  /etc/systemd/logind.conf.d/killusrproc.conf
[Login]
KillUserProcesses=no
```

Switching to "no" was the solution for me!!!
[Just beeing "poettered"](https://openforums.blog/2016/05/31/systemd-defaults-killuserprocesses-to-yes-in-logind-conf-with-v230/)

THANKS!!!

Kind Regards

maniac__